# psycopg2.dataERROR by copying a csv file in a postgreSQL table (using Python)

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a very short csv file with 3 lines:

```
45,55,45
45,12,54
45,45,48
```

I want to copy it in a table of 3 columns on my postgres using python.. I create the table of 3 columns (type: character varying) which worked well. Then I open the file  and try to copy it as follows:

```
f = open('/path/to/file.csv')  
cur.copy_from(f,'table_name',sep=",")

f.close()

conn.commit() 
conn.close()
```

Where `cur` and `conn` are already defined as cursor and conenction.

I always get this error (also when try it with another csv file):

```
psycopg2.DataError: missing data for column "b"
CONTEXT: COPY table_name, line 4
```

What I don't get is that there can't be a missed data because there are in all lines 3 data and I just have 3 columns and the error tells that it's in line 4 .. but I only have 3 lines in my csv file !

HELP :D

Comment: Show output of `\d table_name` in `psql`

Comment: Do you have an empty whitespace line on the end of your csv file?